# Selenium-WebDriverWait() not working just before a if/else statement?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've got a problem with Selenium, it seems that I cannot use a `WebDriverWait()` just before a if/else statement.
The code:

```
WebDriver driver;    
(new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
    public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
        return d.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains("site name");
    }
});
if(stuff!=false){
    return "the good stuff"
}
else{
    return "the bad stuff"
}
```

This code works in any other place, and I cannot seem to find a way to fix this. Does anybody have another way of doing this?

Comment: What is the error/exception when you run this code? Add `;` to the statements within the `if /else` ; I guess that's just a typo.

Comment: What makes you conclude that you cannot use it before an if/else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found a nice bit of code on Selenium's site:

```
WebDriver driver;
int seconds;
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, seconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("id")));
```

This is a much more simplified way of getting a fluent wait. Also, seems to run just fine in all situations.